# Split a WordPress title into two lines

Tags: wordpress, split, title

Here is a Q&A that you might find useful.

Many times I am building a WordPress site and need a page or post to have a title and a sub-title. Rather than creating a meta-box to store the sub-title, I'd like to be able to have the author write the title in the default title box, and then break it into title/sub-title in the code.

For example, here is the title:

"This is the main title - This is the sub-title".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this in your functions.php file will take the title and split it by the ' - ' characters (note it is a space then a hyphen followed by a space).

```
/*
 * Split and wrap title
 */
    function get_split_title($postID) {
        $title = get_the_title($postID);
        $lines = explode(' &#8211; ', $title);
        $output = false;
        $count = 0;

        foreach( $lines as $line ) {
            $count++;
            $output .= '<span class="line-'.$count.'">'.$line.'</span> ';
        }

        return $output;
    }
```

Then in a theme file you can just do this to get the title bake split into lines:

```
<?php echo get_split_title($post->ID); ?>
```

You use CSS and "display:block" to break each span onto a new line if needed. Alternatively you can ad a 
 after the  tag in the above function.

Comment: Maybe simply applying [`the_title` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) and use the same function as callback, so there's no need to modify the templates.

Comment: Yeah thats a good idea if needed, but I like the flexibility of being able to use both.