# Split wordpress Title (Artist - Song name)

Tags: wordpress, text, split, title

is there a way to split the title into 2 text? and split only from the first Hyphen(-)

Sample:

Input: Artist name - Song name

Output:

i found this but its not exactly what i need
[Split a WordPress title into two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416719/split-a-wordpress-title-into-two-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try this :

```
$array = explode('-', 'wordpress-title', 2);

Then echo $array[0]; // output wordpress
echo $array[1];  // output  title
```

Comment: how to i insert this in my theme? i tried this but it didn't work..
<php $array = explode('-', 'wordpress-title', 2); ?>
<php echo $array[0]; ?>
<php echo $array[1]; ?>